# TCP socket error 10061

Tags: c#, tcp, serversocket

I have created a windows service socket programme to lisen on specific port and accept the client request. It works fine.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

      //Lisetns only on port 8030          
       IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8030);

      //Defines the kind of socket we want :TCP
       Socket  serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        //Bind the socket to the local end point(associate the socket to localendpoint)
            serverSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);

            //listen for incoming connection attempt
            // Start listening, only allow 10 connection to queue at the same time
            serverSocket.Listen(10);

           Socket handler = serverSocket.Accept();

    }
```

But I need the service programme to listen on multiple port and accept the client request on any available port.

So I enhanced the application to bind to port 0(zero), so that it can accept the request on any available port.

But then I got the error `10061`

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I am unable to know whats the reason of getting this error.

Can anybody please suggest the way to enhance the code to accept the request on any port.

But  the client need to send request to connect to specific port. e.g client1 should connect to `port 8030`, client2 should connect to `port 8031`.

Comment: Why do you need the clients to send requests to different ports?! That's not a sensible requirement.

Comment: Just have the client send its identification to you. Instead of having it connect on port 8030, have it send you "8030" over the socket. You're making this unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I did not get you exactly. Correct me if I am wrong. you mean to say instead of connecting to port 8030, I should try to send data from port 8030 in client application.

Comment: No. Have every client connect to the same well-known port. It doesn't matter what port they connect from. Your whole reason for using, say, port 8030 was to identify a particular client. So instead of using it as a port, just have that client *send* "8030" to the server, and then you'll know which client it is. You're making this difficult. You're trying to invent caller ID when the person can just tell you who they are after you pick up the phone.

Comment: fine, I got your point. But is it possible to get connected to different port?

Comment: Yes, but again, that makes the problem far more difficult than it needs to be. It opens up lots of cans of worms (such as running out of local ports) for no reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I enhanced the application to bind to port 0(zero), so that it can accept the request on any available port.

Wrong. 0 means that the OS should assign a port. A server can only listen at one port at a time. The listen socket just accepts new connections.

The new connection will have the same local port, but the ***combination*** of Source (ip/port) and destination (ip/port) in the IP header is used to identify the ***connection***. That's why the same listen socket can accept multiple clients.

UDP got support for broadcasts if that's what you are looking for.

**Update:**

A very simplified example

```
  Socket client1 = serverSocket.Accept(); // blocks until one connects
  Socket client2 = serverSocket.Accept(); // same here

  var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HEllo world!");
  client1.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Count); //sending to client 1
  client2.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Count); //sending to client 2
```

Simply keep calling `Accept` for each client you want to accept. I usually use the asynchronous methods (Begin/EndXXX) to avoid blocking.

Comment: If I am not wrong broadcast means sending data to multiple recipient. But I need to receive data from multiple source. So I suppose I don't need broadcast.

Comment: That's why the same listen socket can accept multiple clients.   Yes, we can do that. Can you please suggest me a way to identify the client sending request to same port to server?

Comment: @Madhusmita If the client has some kind of identifier that the server needs to know, just have the client send that identifier to the server. That's the whole point of having the connection -- so the client and server can exchange data.

Comment: It does not assign a new port. The accepted socket uses the same port as the listening socket.