# Connection Refused with TCP socket Error # 10061

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm creating a small chat (1-1) application to learn network programming and when creating the socket using TCP protocol, the Socket.Connect() always return error 10061.
However, if I make the socket UDP, I don't see the issue.

Here is my code:

```
myEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_txtMyIPAdress.Text), int.Parse(_txtMyPort.Text));
TargetSideEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_txtTargetIPAddress.Text), int.Parse(_txtTargetPort.Text));
mySocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
mySocket.Bind(myEndPoint);
mySocket.Connect(TargetSideEndPoint);
byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024];
ReceivePackets(mySocket, receivedBuffer);//My function
```

Can any one help me?
Update:
I'm not using Listen() the issue is when I call Connect()
I already tried multiple ports with the same issue and I'm currently testing on 1 PC by opening 2 instances from my application and using 2 different ports while firewall is off.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TCP socket error 10061](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077606/tcp-socket-error-10061)

Comment: Also check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695224/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0)

Comment: Also post the listener code.

Comment: @Mihai Caracostea Do I have to use a listener with TCP? Because I didn't use any for the UDP and it worked!

Comment: @David Yes, you have to use a listener for TCP and one peer should be the server and the other the client. That is because it uses connections. UDP is a connectionless protocol. That's why it worked without a listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For TCP, which is a connection oriented protocol, you would need a server and a client.

The server must listen for incoming connections and the client should initiate the connection. Then, the client will be able to communicate with the server and exchange data.

Here is a simple working example:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting listener thread");
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(ListenerThreadProc);
    serverThread.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting 500 milliseconds to allow listener to start");
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    Console.WriteLine("Client: Connecting to server");
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 12345);
    Console.WriteLine("Client: Connected to server");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[5];
    Console.WriteLine("Client: Receiving data");
    using (NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream())
        clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("Client: Received data: " + buffer.Aggregate("", (s, b) => s += " " + b.ToString()));     
}

void ListenerThreadProc()
{   
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Server: Listener started");

    Console.WriteLine("Server: Waiting for client to connect");
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("Server: Client connected");

    listener.Stop();    
    Console.WriteLine("Server: Listener stopped");

    Console.WriteLine("Server: Sending data");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };   
    using (NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream())
        clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Server: Sent data");
}
```

In this example, made as simple as it gets, you have a server accepting a single client to which it sends some data. The client connects, reads the data and then displays it.

A real-life server would spin new threads (or tasks, for async model) to serve the client's request as soon as the client would connect and carry on listening for new connections.